# Unable to view cluster on UI that is created by databricks api

Tags: databricks

I am creating a databricks cluster via api but somehow it is not visible on the databricks UI. Please could you suggest if i am missing something.

Also, I have created a group and added users to it, will that give access to this cluster?

Note: I can see that the databricks cluster is created but due to some reason it is in termination state.

```py
def create_cluster():
   data = {
      "cluster_name": "test-cluster",
      "spark_version": "10.1.x-cpu-ml-scala2.12",
      "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
      "autoscale" : {
        "min_workers": 1,
        "max_workers": 2
      }
    }
    
response = requests.post(get_url('/clusters/create'), json=data, headers=HEADERS)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=2))
```

Comment: not visible for you? or for other

Comment: for me and it was permission issue only; I created it with admin token which was not linked to my email address so when i added the relevant permission(using Update cluster permissions for a specific entity) I am able to see the cluster now, thank you :)

Comment: yes, that's an issue - by default clusters aren't visible by anyone except admins/creator, so you need to set permissions after creation